# Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: next.js

```
import BlogData from "./BlogData";
import Link from 'next/link'


function Card(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="post-content">
                <div className="post-image">
                    <Link href={props.to}><a><img srcSet={props.srcset} src={props.src} alt={props.alt} width={props.width} height={props.height} /></a></Link>
                </div>
                <div className="post-data">
                    <Link href={props.to}><a><h2>{props.heading}</h2></a></Link>
                    <p>{props.para}</p>
                    <Link href={props.to}><a><button className="read-more">Read More &nbsp;<i className="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </button></a></Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </>
    )
}



const Blog = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <div className="blogpage">
                    <section className="posts">
                        <h1>Blog Posts</h1>

                        {BlogData.map((val) => {
                            return (
                                <Card key={val.id}
                                srcset={val.srcset}
                                    src={val.src}
                                    alt={val.alt}
                                    width={val.width}
                                    height={val.height}
                                    href={val.to}
                                    heading={val.heading}
                                    para={val.para} />
                            );
                        })
                    }

                    </section>
                </div>

            </main>

        </>

    )
}

export default Blog;
```

There is an error that Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead. I am passing href link using props but getting this error. The card component is used to display the data. I am fetching data from BlogData array where data is stored as an object. Can somebody tell me how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in the wrong prop. As far as I can see you pass `href` prop, but expect `to`

```
<Card
 key={val.id}
 srcset={val.srcset}
 src={val.src}
 alt={val.alt}
 width={val.width}
 height={val.height}
 to={val.to}            // need to change here
 heading={val.heading}
 para={val.para}
/>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why StyledJSX is not working here?